# How to change the color of the terminal when is focused

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is there a way to change the color of the integrated terminal (windows cmd) when its focused/active?

i use ctrl+l to change between the terminal and the working space but sometimes i have problems telling what area is active

```
{
    "key": "ctrl+l", 
    "command": "workbench.action.terminal.focus",
    "when": "!terminalFocus" 
},
{
    "key": "ctrl+l", 
    "command": "workbench.action.focusActiveEditorGroup",
    "when": "terminalFocus" 
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Hopefully there is something better than this but you could try setting your terminal cursor to an obvious color such as red:

```
"workbench.colorCustomizations": {

    //"terminal.background": "#567",
    //"terminal.foreground": "#fff",
    "terminalCursor.foreground": "#f00"
}
```

And then you'll see the terminal cursor change significantly when the terminal gets or loses focus.

Answer (score 4):

Extension [Custom CSS and JS Loader](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=be5invis.vscode-custom-css).

```css
.terminal {
    border-left: 5px solid #41A6D9;
    opacity: 1;
}
.terminal:not(.focus) {
    border-color: transparent;
    opacity: 0.5;
}
```

Comment: This little extension is brilliant! I used similar style definitions but added `padding-left: 1em;` to give a little breathing room between border and text.